# Regarding property of Dedekind sums in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol and I am not able to prove this property of Dedekind sums
$$\sum_{r=0}^k  \left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right) = 0$$
if $\gcd(h, k) =1$ where $((x)) = x-[x] -0.5$ if $x$ is not an integer and $((x)) = 0$ if $x$ is an integer. ($[x]$ denotes greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.)

Apsotol mentions it can be proved using periodic property, that $((x))$ has period $1$ and using that $((x))$ is an odd function. But I can't see how to use these facts.

Can somebody please give a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed
$$\sum_{r=0}^k  \left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}  \left(\left(\frac{hr}{k}\right)\right)=\\
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \left(\frac{hr}{k} - \left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}\right)=\\
\frac{h}{k}\cdot\frac{k(k-1)}{2} - \sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor - \frac{k-1}{2}=\\
\frac{(h-1)(k-1)}{2} - \sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor \tag{1}=...$$
But (by reordering and [because $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor -x \right \rfloor=-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Relations_among_the_functions) for $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$)
$$\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor}=
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{h(k-r)}{k} \right \rfloor=
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor h + \left(- \frac{hr}{k}\right) \right \rfloor=\\
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} h+\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor -\frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor=
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} (h-1)-\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor=\\
(h-1)(k-1)-\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\left \lfloor \frac{hr}{k} \right \rfloor}$$
There are more elegant proofs of this, but this is the one I remember. And finally, continuing $(1)$
$$...=0$$

Comment: Since we are given the assumption $\gcd(h,k) = 1$ (which you didn't use, thus showing it is unnecessary) we could argue that $hr$ runs through a complete residue system modulo $k$ when $r$ does, so by the periodicity the sum is $$\sum_{r = 0}^{k-1} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{r}{k}\biggr)\biggr) = \sum_{r = 1}^{k-1} \biggl(\frac{r}{k} - \frac{1}{2}\biggr) = \frac{k(k-1)}{2k} - \frac{k-1}{2} = 0\,.$$ This is shorter than your proof. Whether it counts as more elegant depends on one's criteria for elegance. But it injects a spurious dependence on the assumption $\gcd(h,k) = 1$.

Comment: This is easily removed, of course, let $d = \gcd(h,k)$ and put $h' = h/d,\, k' = k/d$. Then $$\sum_{r = 0}^{k-1} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{hr}{k}\biggr)\biggr) = \sum_{r = 0}^{k-1} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{h'r}{k'}\biggr)\biggr) = d\cdot \sum_{r = 0}^{k'-1} \biggl(\biggl(\frac{h'r}{k'}\biggr)\biggr) = d\cdot 0 = 0.$$ But that loses any gain in elegance the first part may have had.

Comment: @DanielFischer I meant [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients) (a few lines below) $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor {\frac {im}{n}}\right\rfloor ={\frac {1}{2}}(m-1)(n-1)$. I decided to include a proof, but could have provided a reference instead. The $\gcd(h,k)=1$ is required for $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor -x \right \rfloor=-1$, I didn't mention this.

Comment: Ah, that one. I find it neat to consider the lattice points in the open rectangle $(0,n) \times (0,m)$. With $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ there is no lattice point on the diagonal, half of the lattice points lie above, and half below the diagonal, the sum counts the lattice points below.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that is one in the list of more elegant proofs indeed :) ... but too time consuming for a quick answer (given drawing isn't my strong point).

Comment: I bet your drawing isn't worse than mine. But who needs drawing here? Stating it as above is enough.